# Why I can't do hover?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make two pictures align each other when hovering on one of them but its not working

```
<style>
.div2 img{
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.img-left {
  transform: translate(0%, -10%);
}
.img-right {
  transform: translate(0%, 10%);
}
.div2 img:hover .img-left {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
.div2 img:hover .img-right {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
</style>
<div class="div2">
 <img class="img-left" src="img/trico-left.png">
 <img class="img-right" src="img/trico-right.jpg">
</div>
```

So why isn't this code working

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is going wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: You should use `.div2 img:hover{transform:translate(0%,0%)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch the hover on the parent element if you wanna move both images at the same time

```
.div2:hover img {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

because it's looking for an element with a class "img-left" or "img-right" inside the "img"

the correct answer would be like this

```
.div2 img.img-left:hover {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
.div2 img.img-right:hover {
  transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
```

Comment: Just a note: these two can be also written as a single definition.

Comment: Ahmed hassan that code that you gave is translating only the hovered image i want to translate both two images when hovering on one image